# How to get all ID's fanpage I manage?

Tags: facebook

Can someone help me?
I'm trying to get all id's fanpage I manage.
But no success.
Thank a lot.
P/s: sr, my english not good.
C#, winform.

[Image](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b602/Gin_CanhViet/Capture_zps114960e2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Make the API call-

```
/me/accounts
```

With a valid access token that has the permission manage_pages

Comment: Here, can you read it? Then help me plz
[link]https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/695937420449775/?notif_t=group_comment

Comment: What's the problem? You have the complete json result with you. Cant you just parse that?

Comment: Yes, can see it, but cant get it!